# How do you use a Custom Transition when using the Navigator's PushNamed function in Flutter?

Tags: flutter-animation

I have created named routes and now a custom route transition class which extends **PageRouteBuilder**. I would like to use the custom transition when I change routes using the **pushNamed** function of the Navigator object but I am unsure of how to do this as all examples I see use the **push** function which takes the route object instead of the route name.

What do I need to do to use custom transitions with the pushNamed routes function?

Comment: I eventually solved my issue by specifying the custom route settings for each route using the onGenerateRoute event of the MaterialApp:
      
     <pre><code>onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        switch (settings.name) {
          case "/homepage":
            return new MyCustomRoute(
              builder: (_) => new HomePage(),
              settings: settings,
            );</code></pre>